# Appropriate test for significance of difference between accuracy on unshuffled vs shuffled data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, independence, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

It is common practice in neural decoding studies to compare the decoding accuracy on a data set with the accuracy on the *label-shuffled* data set, and then use a statistical test to determine whether decoding performance on the unshuffled data is significantly higher.

Suppose a dataset consists of $n$ accuracy scores on $n$ sessions or trials, and $n$ accuracies on the corresponding shuffled data. My question is **what would be the most appropriate statistical test to address the difference between the two population means**.

My confusion arises mainly because some studies use a Wilcoxon rank sum test (Mann-Whitney U-test), for example [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23558170), which is a test for **independent** samples. Others, see for example [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27545876), use a paired t-test, which as the name suggests is tailored to **paired** observations.

I would say that a score computed on unshuffled and shuffled data is a *dependent* observation, as there is a one-to-one correspondence between points in each pair, and thus a Wilcoxon rank sum would be inappropriate (the Wilcoxon signed rank test would be a paired-samples nonparametric alternative). I have also noticed that the Wilcoxon rank sum produces lower p-value than the paired t test.

Comment: Are you referring to a permutation test maybe? One where you 'shuffle' the values or labels and check how often across all 'shuffles' a difference from the null-hypothesis is found?

Comment: Not exactly. A permutation test would be where you take the difference between the means of population A (accuracy on unshuffled data) and population B (accuracy on shuffled data) as a test statistic and compare it to the null distribution in which you randomize the 'shuffled' and 'unshuffled' labels. I am not sure whether this test is applicable to paired data. In fact in the first paper I mention they use both Wilcoxon rank sum and this permutation test.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I agree with your explanation of a permutation test, but maybe you could add some sample data to your question to make clear what kind of test (permutation or something else) you are looking for.

Comment: I am referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests]) (section on permutation tests). The data is explained in my question: you have n scores (accuracy or other) on n sessions/trials, and n accuracies on the corresponding shuffled data (each session\trial shuffled independently), and you are interested in whether the mean of the unshuffled population is significantly higher.